# jQuery get text between element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want get text between two element `<p>` and `<b>`, but doesn't work, How is it?

```js
$("div").each(function() {
  var num = $('this').find('p').text();
  var ost = $('this').find('b').text();
  alert(num+' - '+ost);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>1</p>
  <b>Minifier</b>
</div>
<div>
  <p>2</p>
  <b>bold</b>
</div>
<div>
  <p>3</p>
  <b>backtick</b>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('this')` should be `$(this)`, because `this` is a keyword, not a string. You were trying to select an element with a tag type of `<this>`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$(this)` instead of `$('this')` without quotes.

`this` is an available object and not an string selector.

See corrected example below:

```js
$("div").each(function() {
  var num = $(this).find('p').text();
  var ost = $(this).find('b').text();
  alert(num+' - '+ost);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>1</p>
  <b>Minifier</b>
</div>
<div>
  <p>2</p>
  <b>bold</b>
</div>
<div>
  <p>3</p>
  <b>backtick</b>
</div>
```